# Difference between shall and going to?

Tags: grammar

I had a multiple-choice question which was:

> **Let's go to the cinema. What films ____  watch?**
>
> **a) shall we**
>
> **b) are we**
>
> **c) are we going to**
>
> **d) was we**

I chose **c) are we going to** but they took it as wrong? Why?

Comment: I don't see how **a) shall we** is wrong. Shall is just an old fashioned way of saying "will" when the subject is either **I** or **we**. The only case in which **shall** is wrong would have been if your teacher/workbook specifically requested you had used a specific tense.

Comment: IMHO, 1)"_What films shall we watch_".   2) "_What films are we **watching**?_" and. 3) "_What films are we going to watch_" are all OK. However 4) "_What films was we watch?_" is not correct English. I could be "_What films were we watching?_"

Comment: Pardon sir.I chose are we going to

Comment: @Ghost Even after your edit, both **a** and **c** are grammatically correct. Again, the only way in which one of those isn't correct is when you are asked to use a specific tense.

Answer (score 1):

In b) and d) the grammar is wrong.

In a) and c) the grammar is right.

BUT . . .

Going to the cinema is MY suggestion. So it doesn't make sense for me to ask YOU what we are going to watch! Therefore c) is illogical.

a) might also seem illogical, but ***shall we*** sounds as if I'm asking your opinion. It is more reflective than c). It's like **I wonder what we should watch** or **Let's choose**.

So a) is best.